# pass multiple parameters to ProcessBuilder with a space

Tags: java, processbuilder

I would like to pass multiple parameters to a processBuilder and the parameters to be separated by a space.

Here is the command,

```
String[] command_ary = {dir+"library/crc"," -s ", fileName," ",addressRanges};
```

I need to provide a space after "fcrc" and after "-p" and in between "filename" and the "addressRange".

Thank you

Answer (score 28):

You don't need to include spaces. The ProcessBuilder will deal with that for you. Just pass in your arguments one by one, without space:

```
ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder(
                         dir + "library/crc",
                         "-s",
                         fileName,
                         addressRanges);
```

Comment: Ya thats correct but the crc exe which Im using requires space between the crc and -s and between filename and the address ranges passed, otherwise it throws a file not found exception

Comment: @mee are you sure the "file not found" error is not caused by something else?  If you're using a relative path as the `fileName` then you will presumably need to set the correct working directory for the process (using `pb.directory(...)` before you call `pb.start()`)

Answer (score 14):

We need spaces between arguments in commandline because the commandline need to know which is the first argument, which is the second and so on. However when we use `ProcessBuilder`, we can pass an array to it, so we do not need to add those spaces to differentiate the arguments. The ProcessBuilder will directly pass the command array to the `exec` after some checking. For example,

```
private static final String JAVA_CMD = "java";
private static final String CP = "-cp";

private static final String CLASS_PATH = "../bin";
private static final String PROG = "yr12.m07.b.Test";
private static final String[] CMD_ARRAY = { JAVA_CMD, CP, CLASS_PATH, PROG };
ProcessBuilder processBuilder = new ProcessBuilder(CMD_ARRAY);
```

The above code will work perfectly.

Moreover, you can use

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("java -cp C:/testt Test");
```

But it is more convenient to use ProcessBuilder, one reason is that if our argument contains space we need to pass quote in `Runtime.getRuntime().exec()` like `java -cp C:/testt \"argument with space\"`, but with ProcessBuilder we can get rid of it.

```
ProcessBuilder processBuilder = new ProcessBuilder("command", "The first argument", "TheSecondWithoutSpace");
```

Answer (score -4):

Use it like this:

`new java.lang.ProcessBuilder('netstat -an'.toString().split('\\s'))).start()`

Comment: In Java `'` is used for a single character, not a string

Comment: why did I receive down votes, what the heck¿? You haven't used a JSP webshell with 1 parameter it seems, come on, use that `CMD_ARRAY`, now and tell me, are you going to pass a number of parameters based on the command you want to execute¿? Don't make me laugh ...... these down votes I have received should be the other way round OMG!

Comment: This post is several months old dude. Also your code does not compile, that's maybe why your pot was downvoted.