# Compile multiple Java classes at runtime

Tags: java, compilation, h2o

Problem which I am trying to solve:

We have h2o generated file which consists of multiple java classes - one core class which implements interface which is on the classpath and some other classes which holds values used by the core class. Goal is to have ability to load this file at runtime (save in the database) and execute it when needed, without any application restarts.

Some solutions which can be found on the SO are basically used for one class compilation. Which is not suitable at this time.

Comment: And why exactly can you not compile one class at a time, multiple times?

Comment: Use `ProcessBuilder` to execute command through it. If all java files exists in same directory you can compile all files at once using `javac *.java`. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17062219/pass-multiple-parameters-to-processbuilder-with-a-space

Comment: @takendarkk surely that wouldn't work if they were dependant on each other. Especially if they were circularly dependant

Comment: IF they were... well we wouldn't know hence why I asked.

Comment: @takendarkk as I wrote they are dependent on each other and that is the problem