# Add parameters to ProcessBuilder - Java

Tags: java, eclipse, scripting

I want to add paramters to the ProcessBuilder. I have a shell script like this "test.sh"

```
echo "hello"
read user
read pw
```

I want to call this script `"test.sh"` with the Process Builder to give the user and the pw as arguments. That the script is automatically doing this. Otherwise I always have to type in the user and the password..
The username and the pw is always the same, that's the reason why I want to do this automatically.

The full path to the script is here `{/c/users/lia/desktop/test.sh"..}`

So when I execute just the script this in git bash and it is directly here at the desktop with "sh test.sh" I get the content and it works fine..

In my String I have it like this `String[] cmd = {"sh test.sh", "user", "pw"};`

When I convert it into an jar file (I need it later as a jar file) it does not work. Got the message "cannot find file"

When I do it like this : `String [] cmd = {/c/users/lia/desktop/test.sh"..};` it does not work

Thank you all.

Comment: How will you execute .sh file which is shell script in windows ?

Comment: I execute the sh test.sh in git bash its working fine :D

Comment: Possible duplicate of [pass multiple parameters to ProcessBuilder with a space](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17062219/pass-multiple-parameters-to-processbuilder-with-a-space)

Comment: @rghome, might be.. but I still dont get it :(

Comment: The shell script reads from the input. You need to change it to use parameters (e.g., $1, $2, etc).

Comment: "When I convert it into an jar file (I need it later as a jar file) it does not work. Got the message "cannot find file"" You can't run scripts from inside a jar file. You'll need code to extract the script to a temporary directory and run it from there. Also, your users' machines will need to have `sh` available.

Comment: thank you both for your answer. ```echo "hello"
echo "user" $1"
read "pw: $2" ``` and how do I change the java String cmd ?

Answer (score -1):

You can write the shell script like the example given below.

```
echo "hello"
echo "user $1"
echo "pw: $2"
```

Now you have to execute as sh test.sh uname1 pwd1. Use this command in Java ProcessBuilder to execute.

Comment: Hi thank you . I want to add the username and pw as arguments because it is always the same .. dont want to type it always :D

Comment: @Sambit except your answer does not answer the question, has syntax errors and generally doesn't seem to make any sense.

Comment: @rghome maybe it's ```sh /c/users/Lia/desktop/test.sh ``` maybe it's like this and my code at the top?