# Download multiple files from URL to a particular path in linux using curl command (Shell Script)

Tags: java, linux, bash, shell, curl

URL return list of files separated by comma example

URL : http://sometimesdownload.com/list_of_files

To get list of files

curl -0 http://sometimesdownload.com/list_of_files

Output of above curl command/List returned :

["
file1.csv","file2.csv","file3.csv"...."filen.csv"]

How to download all files in a single run  to a specified path in /tmp/downloaded_files directory in linux and delete the file after downloading. File name of files should be same as original files.

**CURL GET** to get the files, Download the files  and then delete the files after downloading using **CURL DELETE**.

File can be downloaded like this :

http://sometimesdownload.com/list_of_files/file_name

**Example:**

curl -o http://sometimesdownload.com/list_of_files/file1.csv

curl -o http://sometimesdownload.com/list_of_files/file2.csv

curl -o http://sometimesdownload.com/list_of_files/file3.csv

Thanks

Comment: What is the meaning of _in a single run_? Do you mean "using a single curl request"? I don't think that `curl` is providing this feature.

Comment: It means executing shell script once... In for loop or any other..

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in Java without curl, but if you want to use curl, you're going to want to use either Runnable.exec or ProcessBuilder. See [pass multiple parameters to ProcessBuilder with a space](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17062219/pass-multiple-parameters-to-processbuilder-with-a-space) for an example

Answer (score 0):

This could be done as something like

```
for i in $(curl http://sometimesdownload.com/list_of_files | jq -c '.[]'); then
    # GET file
    curl -O --output-dir /tmp/downloaded_files http://sometimesdownload.com/"$i"

    # DELETE file
    # However this is mostly not working straightforward and need tuning 
    # as no enough information here about how the files are hosted and 
    # configured by the remote server 
    curl -X DELETE http://sometimesdownload.com/"$i"
done
```

`-c` is the compact output option in `jq` to get the plan text output from a json array.

```
$ echo '["file1.csv","file2.csv","file3.csv"]' | jq -c '.[]'
"file1.csv"
"file2.csv"
"file3.csv"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use below script. Since list syntax is different in BASH, you have to convert to bash syntax. [abc,bca] to (abc bca)

And then you can go throw files one by one and download via CURL.

Here is example script, I believe you can correct it according your env.

```
bashParse() {
    listData=$1
    #validateData
    finalData=()
    echo ${listData} | grep ^"\[" > /dev/null && beginScope=0 || beginScope=1
    echo ${listData} | grep "\]$" > /dev/null && endScope=0   || endScope=1
       
    # build our List BASH stntax    
    if [ $beginScope -eq 0 ] && [ $endScope -eq 0 ] ; then
        # Here I will remove [ and ], also replace last SPACE with nothing => sed
        declare -a finalData=($(echo $listData|tr '\"' ' '| tr -d '[]'| tr ',' ' '))
    fi
    
    # Download files one by one by CURL
    for i in "${finalData[@]}" ; do
       echo "curl://<link>/$i"
    done

}
```

Comment: finalData value : "file1","file2","file3.csv"

not working

Comment: @kamal-chopra , Sorry. it was my bad. I updated script for printing properly bash Array.

Comment: My script is pure bash script. But of  course  you can use jq tool to parse List and Json.